# Add an allowed tag name to the HTML language mode

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I'm using Foundation for Emails, which has a few unique tag names that are later parsed. Specifically, VSCode doesn't seem to like `<spacer>`:

[image]

How do I add `<spacer>` as an known/allowed tag so it's not redded out by VSCode?

Comment: Please don't tag Visual Studio for a VS Code question. They are most definitely not the same.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [HTML custom data](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/html#_html-custom-data). Create a JSON file, e.g. `spacer.html-data.json`:

```json
{
  "version": 1.1,
  "tags": [
    {
      "name": "spacer",
      "description": "Foundation spacer",
      "attributes": [
        {
          "name": "size",
          "description": "Spacer size"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And include it in your [VS Code JSON configuration](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settings-file-locations):

```
"html.customData": [
    "./spacer.html-data.json"
]
```

Note that this has to be a path relative to your opened folder/workspace.

---

**EDIT**: Oh, I just realized that this does not prevent the red colouring in this special case. Probably this is becaue `spacer` used to be a valid HTML tag but [is deprecated now](https://www.w3docs.com/learn-html/html-spacer-tag.html). I have no idea how to change this behaviour in VS code.